# How to re-arrange repeated xml nodes using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest the xslt code for the below problem. I have provided a simple code from the input XML and expected XML. Help will be appreciated if someone can provide XSLT code to tranform input xml in the expected xml.

INPUT XML

```
    <INFOPERSONFILLNOTE>
    <VARIABLELABEL>Level</VARIABLELABEL>
    <SERIALNO1 STATUS="NONE">
    1
    <VARIABLELABEL>S1</VARIABLELABEL>
    <CHANGEDATE/>
    <CHANGEREASON/>
    </SERIALNO1>
    <SERIALNO1 STATUS="NONE">
    2
    <VARIABLELABEL>S2</VARIABLELABEL>
    <CHANGEDATE/>
    <CHANGEREASON/>
    </SERIALNO1>
    <CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE STATUS="NONE">
    c1
    <VARIABLELABEL>C1</VARIABLELABEL>
    <CHANGEDATE>20200226</CHANGEDATE>
    <CHANGEREASON>cr</CHANGEREASON>
    </CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE>
    <CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE STATUS="NONE">
    c2
    <VARIABLELABEL>C2</VARIABLELABEL>
    <CHANGEDATE>20200226</CHANGEDATE>
    <CHANGEREASON>cr</CHANGEREASON>
    </CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE>
   </<INFOPERSONFILLNOTE>
```

EXPECTED XML:

```
    <INFOPERSONFILLNOTE>
    <VARIABLELABEL>Level</VARIABLELABEL>
    <SERIALNO1 STATUS="NONE">
    1
    <VARIABLELABEL>S1</VARIABLELABEL>
    <CHANGEDATE/>
    <CHANGEREASON/>
    </SERIALNO1>
    <CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE STATUS="NONE">
    c1
    <VARIABLELABEL>C1</VARIABLELABEL>
    <CHANGEDATE>20200226</CHANGEDATE>
    <CHANGEREASON>cr</CHANGEREASON>
    </CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE>
    <SERIALNO1 STATUS="NONE">
    2
    <VARIABLELABEL>S2</VARIABLELABEL>
    <CHANGEDATE/>
    <CHANGEREASON/>
    </SERIALNO1>
    <CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE STATUS="NONE">
    c2
    <VARIABLELABEL>C2</VARIABLELABEL>
    <CHANGEDATE>20200226</CHANGEDATE>
    <CHANGEREASON>cr</CHANGEREASON>
    </CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE>
   </<INFOPERSONFILLNOTE>
```

Kindly Help.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="INFOPERSONFILLNOTE">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="VARIABLELABEL"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="SERIALNO1|CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE">
            <xsl:sort select="number(translate(VARIABLELABEL, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ''))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<INFOPERSONFILLNOTE>
<VARIABLELABEL>Level</VARIABLELABEL>
<SERIALNO1 STATUS="NONE">
1
<VARIABLELABEL>S1</VARIABLELABEL>
<CHANGEDATE/>
<CHANGEREASON/>
</SERIALNO1><CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE STATUS="NONE">
c1
<VARIABLELABEL>C1</VARIABLELABEL>
<CHANGEDATE>20200226</CHANGEDATE>
<CHANGEREASON>cr</CHANGEREASON>
</CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE><SERIALNO1 STATUS="NONE">
2
<VARIABLELABEL>S2</VARIABLELABEL>
<CHANGEDATE/>
<CHANGEREASON/>
</SERIALNO1><CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE STATUS="NONE">
c2
<VARIABLELABEL>C2</VARIABLELABEL>
<CHANGEDATE>20200226</CHANGEDATE>
<CHANGEREASON>cr</CHANGEREASON>
</CLASSPERSONFILLNOTE>
</INFOPERSONFILLNOTE>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am new to XSLT and don't know how to incorporatre the codes for multiple transforms within the xml in a single XSLT. Would really appreciate your efforts if you can help me acheive the below transformation. I am writing a different question with complete input and expected xml. Thank you again for your help . Really appreciate your support.